# How to count number of same elements from data using PHP

Tags: php, foreach, count, strstr

I'm trying to count frequency from input data.
Here is e.g input including Y value / X value / User Key

```
Y:5, X:3, User:A
Y:12, x:1, User:B
Y:66, X:2, User:A
Y:180, X:3, User:C
Y:328, X:4, User:D
Y:549, X:3, User:D
Y:765, X:2, User:A
```

Most important value is Y. I want to count each user's number of frequency each user have.

- Y : 1~100
- Y : 100~500
- Y : 500~1000

I want this output of the counts of each user value like this :
(Each [value] will be used to insert to database)

```
[User Key] [Total counting] [1~100] [100~500] [500~1000]
User [A] have [3] data, [2] [0] [1]
User [B] have [1] data, [1] [0] [0]
User [C] have [1] data, [0] [1] [0]
User [D] have [2] data, [0] [1] [1]
```

I tried simply divide data to rows like this :

```
foreach ($input as $row) {
echo substr(strstr( $row, 'User:'), 5)
}
```

And I don't have any idea to count each Users. I'm still learning, and I would appreciate your help.

Comment: first you need to group each user, then get ready to have 3 conditions, like your criteria above, and group them in another array, each iteration push it inside. then another foreach to present the tally

Comment: @Kevin How can I group each user? Could you give me an example of how that works?

Comment: it will depend on how the input is supplied. how is that x y user given to you? like from a form? or from a text file formatted like that above?

Comment: @Kevin X, Y, User information given like first form. (Y:5, X:3, User:A...)
I'm struggling with converting and counting the username into a variable... (Each User [name])